# JavaScript heap out of memory when building react project in python subprocess

Tags: python, node.js, npm, subprocess

I want to automate the deployment of a react app on my server. I have a github webhook event that hits a python Flask endpoint where I then run `npm run build:stage` in a subprocess.

**If I run the build command in an ssh login session, it works fine** and the build generates but when the webhook fires and the command is run through the python subprocess, I see the following error:

Python code that executes the command:

```
p = subprocess.Popen(command,
cwd=cwd,
stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
stderr=subprocess.PIPE,
shell=True)
```

```
09/05/2020 02:42:59 PM +08 : INFO : Process Output: 
> laravel-app@0.1.0 build:stage /home/user/reactapp
> env-cmd -f .env.prod react-scripts build

Creating an optimized production build...

<--- Last few GCs --->

[5541:0x2bc1760]    19190 ms: Scavenge 524.4 (551.5) -> 516.9 (554.2) MB, 10.4 / 0.0 ms  (average mu = 0.989, current mu = 0.988) allocation failure 
[5541:0x2bc1760]    19217 ms: Scavenge 528.1 (555.1) -> 528.0 (559.4) MB, 16.6 / 0.0 ms  (average mu = 0.989, current mu = 0.988) allocation failure 
[5541:0x2bc1760]    19432 ms: Scavenge 533.1 (560.0) -> 532.7 (563.7) MB, 209.0 / 0.0 ms  (average mu = 0.989, current mu = 0.988) allocation failure 


<--- JS stacktrace --->
Cannot get stack trace in GC.

09/05/2020 02:42:59 PM +08 : ERROR : Process Error: FATAL ERROR: Scavenger: semi-space copy Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! laravel-app@0.1.0 build:stage: `env-cmd -f .env.prod react-scripts build`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the laravel-app@0.1.0 build:stage script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/user/.npm/_logs/2020-09-05T06_42_59_795Z-debug.log
```

After going through [Link 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62469659/scavenger-allocation-failed-javascript-heap-out-of-memory), [Link 2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57924320/1783688), [Link 3](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61263408/1783688)

I added the following to my bashrc
`export NODE_OPTIONS=--max_old_space_size=4096 --max-semi-space-size=4096000`

and updated my build command to:
`"build:stage": "env-cmd -f .env.prod react-scripts --max_old_space_size=4096 --max-semi-space-size=4096000 build"`

The error changed to:

```
09/05/2020 03:10:16 PM +08 : INFO : Process Output:
> laravel-app@0.1.0 build:stage /home/user/reactapp
> env-cmd -f .env.prod react-scripts --max_old_space_size=4096 --max-semi-space-size=4096000 build

Creating an optimized production build...

<--- Last few GCs --->

[7923:0x2e1d950]    33699 ms: Scavenge 415.5 (451.4) -> 412.5 (535.7) MB, 37.8 / 0.0 ms  (average mu = 0.858, current mu = 0.000) allocation failure 
[7923:0x2e1d950]    33913 ms: Scavenge 474.0 (542.3) -> 438.2 (546.6) MB, 36.2 / 0.0 ms  (average mu = 0.858, current mu = 0.000) allocation failure 
[7923:0x2e1d950]    34236 ms: Scavenge 480.8 (549.1) -> 454.3 (567.2) MB, 77.7 / 0.0 ms  (average mu = 0.858, current mu = 0.000) allocation failure 


<--- JS stacktrace --->
Cannot get stack trace in GC.

09/05/2020 03:10:16 PM +08 : ERROR : Process Error: FATAL ERROR: NewSpace::Rebalance Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory
 1: 0x9d8da0 node::Abort() [node]
 2: 0x9d9f56 node::OnFatalError(char const*, char const*) [node]
 3: 0xb37dbe v8::Utils::ReportOOMFailure(v8::internal::Isolate*, char const*, bool) [node]
 4: 0xb38139 v8::internal::V8::FatalProcessOutOfMemory(v8::internal::Isolate*, char const*, bool) [node]
 5: 0xce34f5  [node]
 6: 0xd2a8ae  [node]
 7: 0xd2e627 v8::internal::MarkCompactCollector::CollectGarbage() [node]
 8: 0xcef049 v8::internal::Heap::MarkCompact() [node]
 9: 0xcefdb3 v8::internal::Heap::PerformGarbageCollection(v8::internal::GarbageCollector, v8::GCCallbackFlags) [node]
10: 0xcf0925 v8::internal::Heap::CollectGarbage(v8::internal::AllocationSpace, v8::internal::GarbageCollectionReason, v8::GCCallbackFlags) [node]
11: 0xcf1fcf v8::internal::Heap::HandleGCRequest() [node]
12: 0xca0fb4 v8::internal::StackGuard::HandleInterrupts() [node]
13: 0xfef887 v8::internal::Runtime_StackGuard(int, unsigned long*, v8::internal::Isolate*) [node]
14: 0x13725d9  [node]
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! laravel-app@0.1.0 build:stage: `env-cmd -f .env.prod react-scripts --max_old_space_size=4096 --max-semi-space-size=4096000 build`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the laravel-app@0.1.0 build:stage script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/user/.npm/_logs/2020-09-05T07_10_16_341Z-debug.log
```

```
# npm -v
6.12.0
# node -v
v12.13.0
```

Server: CentOS Linux release 7.6.1810 (Core)

No clue how to proceed further

UPDATE:

I upgraded my hosting plan to increase the RAM from 4GB to 6GB. Now if I run the python snipper in a python console, the build generates fine but when it runs via the webhook throught flask app, I still see it fail with the above error.

Comment: Ultimately, I was unable to get this to work and moved our react app hosting to the [vercel.com](https://vercel.com)

Answer (score 1):

I had exactly the same problem running "npm audit fix" via python subprocess.run. I got it fixed via moving this part into a script and executing the shell (bash in my case) with the script from within my Python script.